# Blazor Secure Api

Tags: api, authentication, razor, blazor, authorization

I am developing an Application in Microsoft Blazor. I have secured all the UI Pages using a custom AuthenticationStateProvider class which searches for a cookie on the browser.

The by restricting the @Body on the MainLayout.razor every page is secured and not readable when the user is not autorized.

```
   <div class="page">
       <Sidebar />

        <div class="main">
            <Header />

            <article class="content px-4">
                <AuthorizeView>
                    <NotAuthorized>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <p>Please sign in to use the Platform...</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </NotAuthorized>
                    <Authorized>
                       @Body
                    </Authorized>
                </AuthorizeView>
            </article>

        </div>
    </div>
```

The issue is that the ./api endpoint is still accessible for not authorized users as the controllers are still active.

```
    [Route("api/User")]
    [ApiController]
    public class Controller_User : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly Interface_User _IUser;

        public Controller_User(Interface_User iUser)
        {
            _IUser = iUser;
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("/api/user/view")]
        public async Task<List<User>> GetUsers()
        {
            try { return await Task.FromResult(_IUser.GetUsers()); }
            catch { throw; }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas how we can secure all ./api urls at once like the razor pages?

Comment: If this is a WASM application with an API then you are dealing with two separate authentication processes.  How do you pass your "cookie" data in the header to your web server and authenticate that information.  You need to authenticate the API request before you can authorize it.  Once you have a `ClaimsPrincipal` you can build a "base" controller that defines the authorization and inherit any controllers that require authorization for the base.

Comment: Yes is WASM and I am storing a username with localstorage on sign in, so if CustomAuthStateProvider reads this username from localstorage it changes the state. Do you have an example for basic controller?

Comment: See some example code in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using inheritance to apply Authorization to controllers.

Two abstract controllers

```cs
[Authorize]  
public abstract class AuthorizedController: Controller {}

[Authorize(Policy = "AdminOnly")]
public abstract class AdminOnlyAuthorizedController: Controller {}
```

And then some implementations

```cs
public sealed class WeatherForecastController: AuthorizedController {  
//....
}

public sealed class WeatherLocationController: AuthorizedController {  
//....

public class MyAdminController: AdminOnlyAuthorizedController {  
//....
}
```